# Rest Kit Entity Mapping a Nested Array

Tags: core-data, restkit

Hi i have a JSON in the following format:

```
{
"entityList": [
    {
     "type": "Author",
     "code" : "XYZ"
       "Books": [
       {
         "id": 10,
    "name": "book1"
         "publisher": {
           "code": "ABC"
            }
       }
     ],
   }
]
}
```

These are the entites

```
@interface Author :NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * type;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * code;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray* Books;

@end

@interface Book :NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Publisher* publisher;

@end


@interface Publisher :NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * code;

@end
```

here is the mapping

```
 RKEntityMapping* Authormapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Author" inManagedObjectStore:[RKObjectManager sharedManager].managedObjectStore];

    // setup the identification Attribute
    Authormapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"code"];
    // set up the attribute mapping

    [Authormapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"code":@"code",@"Books":@"Books"
}];

RKEntityMapping* Bookmapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Book" inManagedObjectStore:[RKObjectManager sharedManager].managedObjectStore];
Bookmapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"id"];
    // set up the attribute mapping

    [Bookmapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"id":@"id"
[l_mapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"publisher"
                                                                              toKeyPath:@"publisher"                                        withMapping:[Publisher getMappingForRelationship]]];
```

This just has Books with an array of dictionaries i can't figure out how to make the NsArray contain objects of Book entites. Thank you very much for the help.

@wain: when i make a relationship in core data the class becomes

```
@interface Author :NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * type;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * code;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Book* Books;

@end
```

And then i use relation ship mapping to map books. but then it will only be one book. I can't see how i will set Books as NSSet*/NSArray* and also declare it as a relation ship to Author in Core data. I don't know how to set up the mapping. if not too much trouble, could you please give a code sample. Thank you very much.

Comment: Why `NSArray`? In Core Data you should be using relationships, so it should be `NSSet`. Then just use `RKRelationshipMapping`.

Comment: So, this should be @property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet* Books and the mapping will be [Authormapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"Books"                toKeyPath:@"Books"                                        withMapping:[Book getMapping]]; am i right?

Comment: and when i do that i get NSManagedObjects of entity 'Author' do not support -mutableSetValueForKey: for the property 'Books'. BTW books is an attribute of Author.

Comment: Did you create the relationships and regenerate the managed object subclasses?

Comment: Yes i did, and that fills the table of all the books. But how do i refer to those Book entity from Author entity?

Comment: So now when you have an `author` instance, you can do `author.books` to get the relationship contents. I'm not clear what you're asking above that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for not replying soon. Wain's solution is correct. The reason i was missing the link was because of an svn issue where in my old file was still showing up and so all the core data generated methods and NSSet were missing. For those who are new to RestKit/ core data and come across this problem. if you have an nest array of objects of a core data entity to be mapped make a " one to many " relationship. and please make sure you regenerate the classes. The best would be delete the old ones .